# how to add an INDENTED line at the beginning of each method in many files?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I want to add a tracing line to each method in many C# files (see example below), and I want to do this automatically, of course.

My approach would be to use regex to match lines starting with `public` or `private`, don't have `;` (exclude members), have parentheses (exclude class definitions), up to opening `{`, all this spanning multiple lines, and add my line after this.

`sed` would be my natural choice, but unfortunately it is less suited for matching over multiple lines.

I almost don't know perl but I managed the following:

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/((private|public)[^;]*?\)\s*?{)/\1\nActivityLoggers.traceMethod();/igs' testFile.cs
```

This works fine but I'd like to add the line indented. Assuming that the `{` is always on a separate line I could just reuse it replacing the `{` with my text, but here my not knowing perl blocks me. Would appreciate any help.

**As a bonus**, you could help exclude constructors :)

**EXAMPLE:**
Make this

```
public partial class AClass : BClass
{
    private static string name;
    private void Method1(int i, string s)
    {
        doSomethng();
    }
    public void Method2
                   (int i, string s)
    {
        doSomethngElse();
    }
 }
```

into this

```
public partial class AClass : BClass
{
    private static string name;
    private void Method1(int i, string s)
    {
        ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();
        doSomethng();
    }
    public void Method2
                   (int i, string s)
    {
        ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();
        doSomethngElse();
    }
 }
```

( In case you're wandering I do fetch the calling method and class names in `traceMethod()` using `StackTrace` :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to work off of what you posted, use this pattern

```
((private|public)[^;]*?\)\s*?{)(?=\R+(\s+))
```

and replace with

```
$1\n$3ActivityLoggers.traceMethod()
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/347)

Comment: @davka, please consider accepting the answer if it suits your request.

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
sed '/\(private\|public\)[^;]*/, /\}/ {
        /\(^[ \t]*\)\([^(]*();\)/ s//\1ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();\n\1\2\n/;
}' sourcefile
```

`/\(private\|public\)[^;]*/, /\}/` defines a pattern space with a range of lines between private|public  and next line containing a `}` (= the end of method block)

In each block that match, we search for the pattern method and apply the substitution, adding the new line using groups

Comment: interesting, mind explaining? my understanding is that sed reads input line  by line, so you can't match multiple lines without a script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/^\s*(public|private)/,/^\s*\{\s*$/{/^\s*\{\s*$/!b;n;/^\s*(public|private)/ba;h;s/\S.*/ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();/p;g}' file
```

This looks for the range starting with `public` or `private` and ending with a `{` on a line by itsself. It then reads the next line and if this begins with `public` or `private` loops. Otherwise it copies the line and replaces everything from the indent by the required string and prints this. It then  retrieves the copied line and prints that.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `gensub()`:

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/((private|public)[^;)]+\)\s*{)(\s*)/,"\\1\\3ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();\\3","g")}' file  
public partial class AClass : BClass
{
    private static string name;
    private void Method1(int i, string s)
    {
        ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();
        doSomethng();
    }
    public void Method2
                   (int i, string s)
    {
        ActivityLoggers.traceMethod();
        doSomethngElse();
    }
}
```